# I'm trying to get my Nuget packages from Team Services but i get an error

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, azure-devops

> Unable to load the service index for source -my source-. Key not valid
>   for use in specified state.

error from Package Manager Console:

> Install-Package : Some NuGet packages are missing from the solution.
>   The packages need to be restored in order to build the dependency
>   graph. Restore the packages  before performing any operations. At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Owasp.Esapi -Source My Source ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetMissingPackages,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

another error:
[image]

**steps to add VSTS Package Feed and install the package**

**Producing NuGet Packages**

The process is quite simple. First you need a package feed to send the NuGet package to. Create this by clicking the Package link inside the project and click "New feed", giving it a name like "default" (we are unlikely to create more than one in each project). Leave the options and choose Create.

This creates a feed URL that looks something like this: https://example.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/example/nuget/v3/index.json Copy it and then add 2 extra NuGet build steps to the CI build:

[image]

Notice they are different steps. One is Packager, the other Publisher. You could publish it multiple times but only need to package it once.

In the settings for Packager, set Automatic package versioning to "Use the build number" otherwise it will not overwrite older versions.

In the settings for the Publisher, Set "Feed type" to be "Internal NuGet Feed" and paste your feed URL into the URL box.

Under the General tab, set the build number format to $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r)

Click save and Queue a build to ensure it has worked correctly.

Go back to the Package tab and ensure your feed now has a package displayed. Click "Connect to feed" near the top to show this dialog and then click Personal Access Tokens:

[image]

NOTE THE WARNING. You cannot re-show this password so record it somewhere for now ideally KeePass. Copy the entire string including the nuget bit at the start. You will need this after setting up NuGet in the dependent project.

This completes the creation side of the Nuget package, this can now be consumed by other projects.

**Consuming PixelPin NuGet Packages**

Now that you have a project producing a NuGet package and another library that needs to consume it, you need to do a few things. You will need to modify your local NuGet config to Build the project in Visual Studio but you will also need to configure NuGet to run correctly on VSTS which won't be using your local feeds file.

Local Setup
Right-click your project and choose Manage NuGet packages, you should use VS 2015. When the page comes up, click the cog on the right-hand side to bring up your feed settings. Under package sources, if you don't already have it, add a new source with a suitable name and paste in JUST THE URL that you used earlier for creating the package. When you click OK, it will probably ask you to enter credentials. Use the username (usually "support") and the password you got earlier. This should allow you to browse the feed and select the library you want.

Selecting the library you want should install it exactly as per a normal NuGet package and your local project should now build (assuming you don't have other errors of course).

Setup for VSTS
VSTS online will not see or use your NuGet configuration, so you need to add some files, set them up and configure your VSTS build to use them.

```
1) Create a nuget.config file in the root of your solution, you can copy one from another project.
2) Also copy NuGet.exe from another project and put it in the root. Reference both of these files in your solution so you can add them to source control.
3) Run up a command prompt, change directory into the root of your solution and run the command you copied earlier from the Connect to Feed dialog. It will be something like this: NuGet sources Add -Name feedName -Source https://example.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/test/nuget/v3/index.json -UserName support -Password 324oui25b3bi1235ob -ConfigFile .\nuget.config
4) NOTE the last bit which points to your solution copy of nuget.config rather than the default which will be your local machine copy. If it works OK, open the config file to check that you have an entry under packageSources for the name you specified and an entry for packageSourceCredentials with a username and encrypted password.
5) If you somehow get it wrong, you can delete the credentials and package source manually and run the command again but be careful not to remove any other entries that are already there. You can also use NuGet sources Update instead of Add, which should update what is already there.
6) Once you have done this, check in the nuget.config and nuget.exe so they are copied up to the VSTS project. If you check everything in, the next CI build will probably fail but don't worry.
7) Edit your build again and click on the NuGet restore step. Edit the "Path to NuGet.config" and navigate to the nuget.config you just uploaded. (You won't use NuGet.exe on VSTS but it's there in case you need to use it locally again).
```

Queue another build and make sure that the package restore step works OK and that your dependent package is now pulled in as part of the normal build!

Comment: Can you share more detailed information like the steps to add VSTS Package Feed and install the package? And also share the entire error logs if possible.

Comment: @Eddie - MSFT the whole steps to add VSTS package feed and install the package?

Comment: Yes,  the whole steps.

Comment: @Eddie - MSFT I've made the changes

Comment: You mentioned that you clicked "Personal Access Token" in your steps? Do you add the nuget feed via the command generated after clicking PAT?

Comment: And similar issue for your reference: https://github.com/JetBrains/meta-runner-power-pack/issues/75, there is a workaround in it you can try with.

Comment: We found the solution, Visual Studio wasn't updating the Nuget.Config file, leaving it with the wrong credentials